# rsnapshot: WARNING: Some files and/or directories in / vanished during rsync operation

Tags: rsync, centos6, rsnapshot

I once in a while get this message in my rsnapshot log, and an identical message in `/var/log/messages`.  Unfortunately, there is no other deviation from normal output, despite `loglevel 5` in `/etc/rsnapshot.conf`, besides a summary warning at the end:

```
[24/Feb/2014:11:00:02] /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily: started
[24/Feb/2014:11:00:02] Setting locale to POSIX "C"
[24/Feb/2014:11:00:02] echo 9045 > /.../temp/rsnapshot.pid
[24/Feb/2014:11:00:02] /bin/rm -rf /mnt/backup/.snapshots/daily.5/
[24/Feb/2014:11:00:48] mv /mnt/backup/.snapshots/daily.4/ /mnt/backup/.snapshots/daily.5/
[24/Feb/2014:11:00:48] mv /mnt/backup/.snapshots/daily.3/ /mnt/backup/.snapshots/daily.4/
[24/Feb/2014:11:00:48] mv /mnt/backup/.snapshots/daily.2/ /mnt/backup/.snapshots/daily.3/
[24/Feb/2014:11:00:48] mv /mnt/backup/.snapshots/daily.1/ /mnt/backup/.snapshots/daily.2/
[24/Feb/2014:11:00:48] mv /mnt/backup/.snapshots/daily.0/ /mnt/backup/.snapshots/daily.1/
[24/Feb/2014:11:00:48] mkdir -m 0755 -p /mnt/backup/.snapshots/daily.0/
[24/Feb/2014:11:00:48] /usr/bin/rsync -a --delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded --exclude={/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/lost+found,/home/srv/recycle/*} --exclude=mnt/backup/.snapshots --link-dest=/mnt/backup/.snapshots/daily.1/.../ /. /mnt/backup/.snapshots/daily.0/.../
[24/Feb/2014:11:02:13] Some files and/or directories in / vanished during rsync operation
[24/Feb/2014:11:02:13] touch /mnt/backup/.snapshots/daily.0/
[24/Feb/2014:11:02:13] No directory to delete: /mnt/backup/.snapshots/_delete.9045
[24/Feb/2014:11:02:13] rm -f /home/kev/scheduled/temp/rsnapshot.pid
[24/Feb/2014:11:02:13] WARNING: /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily: completed, but with some warnings
```

What could it be?  Why doesn't it report which files vanished even though I have it on the highest loglevel?  (Or do I not even have the loglevel setting right?  Because this doesn't seem very verbose.)

Answer (score 4):

The lastest source distribution of rsync contains this wrapperscript called
rsync-no-vanished:

```
#!/bin/bash

IGNOREEXIT=24
IGNOREOUT='^(file has vanished: |rsync warning: some files vanished before they could be transferred)'

set -o pipefail

rsync "${@}" 2>&1 | (egrep -v "$IGNOREOUT" || true)
ret=$?

if [[ $ret == $IGNOREEXIT ]]
then
        ret=0
fi

exit $ret
```

Answer (score 2):

> Some files and/or directories in / vanished during rsync operation

It means exactly that. RSync creates a list of all the files that have changed since the last time it was run using a "quick check" algorithm (by default) that looks for files that have changed in size or in last-modified time ([rsync(1)](http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html)). This warning is reporting that files or directories in the file list no longer exist at the time rsync tried to copy them to your destination.

The files that have changed are most likely temporary files but if you wanted to verify this you can configure rsnapshot to pass rysnc the `--list-only` option to build the file list, wait an appropriate amount of time, run it again and compare the two to see what files have "disappeared".

Comment: If that's all it is, why is this even a warning?  Are you not allowed to delete files or have temporary files?  How can I shut this off so my fancy job-output-comparer isn't claiming that my backup 'failed' randomly?

Comment: @Kev - You'll have to take that up with the author of rsync. You could try changing the verbosity to hide the message, however I think your best course of action would be to modify your job-output-comparer.

Comment: That's really unfortunate, but OK.

Comment: Also, how come the 'file has vanished' output that I read about other people getting from their cronjobs from rsync does not appear in the log despite loglevel 5?  That's more what my question was getting at.